# How do I find out which PHP files are being served by apache

Tags: apache-httpd

this could be a duplicate but I couldn't find the proper answer. Recently my server has been reporting high CPU usage and I want to find out what was causing that. When I used htop it showed me a bunch of apache2 processes so I guess one of my PHP scripts is probably being served however I would like to know which script exactly is causing that. Is there any way to do that? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Comment: You should see apache logs it shows which php files are accessed

Comment: Apache logs are in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable apache's [server-status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html#troubleshoot) so you can see what is busy. You can see a live
example output at [apache.org](https://www.apache.org/server-status).

Answer (score 1):

You can use follow option with the `tail` command. eg.

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
```

Then you almost can see which files are served in realtime.

You can also `tail -f` the other relevant files in the same location:

```
error.log
access.log
```

You could also get a more detailed realtime view from the command line via goaccess.

[UNIXMEN - GO ACCESS Tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/use-goaccess-web-log-analyzer-apache-debian-7/)